# Monitoring val_loss while training

Tags: machine-learning, keras, monitoring, loss-function

I have a simple question that has made me doubt my work all of a sudden.

If I only have a training and validation set, am I allowed to monitor val_loss while training or is that adding bias to my training. I want to test my accuracy at the end of training on my validation set but suddenly I am thinking if I am monitoring that dataset while training, that'd be problematic? or no?

Comment: After training you should test the accuracy on a completely unseen test set. Results on the validation set at the end of training will give an overestimation of the model's generalisation ability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - yes, monitoring validation error and using it as a basis for decision about specific set up of algorithm adds bias to your algorithm. To elaborate a bit:

1) You fix hyperparameters of any ML algorithm and than train it on train set. Your resulting ML algorithm **with specific set up of hyperparameters** overfits to training set and you use validation set to estimate which performance you can get with these hyperparameters on unseen data

2) But you obviously want to adjust your hyperparameters to get best performance. You may be doing a gridsearch or something like it to get best hyperparameter settings for this specific algorithm using validation set. As result **your hyperparameter settings overfit to validation set**. Think of it as some of the information about validation set still leaks into your model through hyperparameters

3) As result you must do the following: split data set into training set, validation set and test set. Use training set for training, use validation set to make a decision about specific hyperparameters. When you are done (fully done!) with fine tuning your model you must use test set which model have never seen to get an estimation of the final performance in the combat mode.

Comment: I get your point. However, hyperparameters won’t be modified based on my validation set if I’m only using it to monitor the training and save the best outcome based on Val_loss! Or am I missing some point.